# Change the meta description on a specific page?

Tags: description, bloginfo

I want to change the title and meta description on my homepage if it's opened on an android phone.

I have this code that changes the title, inside functions.php:

```
/**
 Modify the front/home page title for Android devices
**/
add_filter( 'wp_title', function( $title )
{
    return
        ( is_front_page() || is_home() )
        && isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) 
        && false !== stripos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'android' )
        ? 'Title Test'
        : $title;
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

This code works!

I am now trying to figure out how to change the meta description.

There is no filter for the meta description, I'm not so sure how the `bloginfo('description')` function work yet. I used `echo bloginfo('description');` on the header.php file and got:

> Just another WordPress site

Which is definitely not my meta description.

As far I understood, the description comes from the the theme (?).

**Updates:**

- I can't add `<meta name="description" content="test description ?>" />`
  to the `<head>` - It adds it to the existing one and doesn't take over it.
- I tried running the two functions the commenter [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-somebody-please-tell-me-how-to-use-the-bloginfo-filter?replies=3) suggested and it didn't work

  ```
  /**
   Modify the front/home page meta description for Android devices
  **/
  add_filter('option_blogdescription','replace_description');
  function replace_description($description) {
      if ( (is_front_page() || is_home()) && isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) && false !== stripos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'android' ) ){    
          $description = "test description";
      }
      return $description;
  }

  function replace_description($info, $show) {
    if ($show == 'description') {
      $info = "test android";
    }
  return $info;
  }
  add_filter('bloginfo','replace_description',PHP_INT_MAX);
  ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *meta description* isn't part of the *Twenty Fifteen* theme.

You mentioned the *Yoast* plugin in a previous question yesterday, so I guess the meta description comes from there.

According to their [API page](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/api/), there's a filter called `wpseo_metadesc` that might be what you're looking for.

Here's an untested example:

```
/**
 * Change the Yoast meta description for Android devices on the front/home page.
 */
add_filter( 'wpseo_metadesc', function( $description )
{
    return 
        ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) 
        && isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) 
        && false !== stripos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'android' )
        ? 'Some Android description!'
        : $description;

}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

Comment: I tried this a few hours ago too, I get a blank page.

Comment: hmm.. I copied and pasted the code, still getting a blank page.. I don't think this is it :X

Comment: this one worked :O 
TNX!

Comment: +1 for the `PHP_INT_MAX`